# What is the relation between fasterxml(jackson-dataformat-xml) and Woodstox?

Tags: xml-parsing, fasterxml

I am sorry if my question is invalid but wanted to know what's the relation between fasterxml(jackson-dataformat-xml) and  Woodstox. The documentation(https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) suggests me to add maven dependency of Woodstox while using jackson-dataformat-xml.

Answer (score 4):

The jackson-dataformat-xml project does not like the Stax implementation provided by the JDK (at least not the one provided by JDK 8).

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/32#issuecomment-236204012 has more information, but ultimately you will need a Stax replacement (like woodstox) if you want to use the library.